# url to navigate local floder like C or D

Tags: html

```html
<html><body><a href="C:\test.txt">File</a> (or) <a href="C:\test.pdf">File</a></body> </html>
```

When i am click hyperlinks browser displaying below error.
"The address wasn't understood".
This is URL in browser-->c:\test.PDF.
But if i manual change c to Capital letter of C i am getting my output.
Is there any way to display directly with capital of driver name in URL.
Please help out for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to access a file on your C drive from a page on the internet..?

Comment: Yes,My code is working when i change link manually in browser  c\test.pdf to C\test.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `file:///` before the link.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="file:///C:\test.txt">File</a>
<a href="file:///C:\test.pdf">File</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Try that and see if it works.

EDIT: keep in mind that it may work on some browsers and not on other.
This is because you are not supposed to access local files from internet.
Exe files are most likely completly blocked because of security.
If it was not blocked you could link to a file called `uninstall.exe`

Comment: file:/// this not working.My problem is why small c is displaying in browser i was given it as Capital C.If i change c letter to C it is working.

Comment: @SrikanthP if it doesn't work there is a reason for it. Security. It's quite obvious that you can't know if and where a user has a file so this page is most likely for your own use or someone close to you. I would recommend you to use a different method. Make a real program with a normal languge such as c or similar, use excel, word or any other local powerful software. You'd be amazed how much you can do with excel and vba. But this project does not sound like it's supposed to be a webpage for public access.

Comment: Again. It's because of safety and security. Most modern browsers block this feature.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt face any issue while running the same code on our system and moreover the way you are using to open a  file is correct so there must be some other issue.
Please verify it once again